# Stuck in confusion over Master / Origin / Branch when cloning

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Thanks for taking a look. Firstly I wouldn't class myself as a GIT expert and can see I have much to learn although I am not a complete novice.

I setup a local server that contains a repo started from bare and I cloned it using Windows Tortoise GIT; I can push back all fine.

I needed to have a version that was a few commits behind running at the same time which I did by cloning and reverting back. I thought this would be simple but I had to do a few things (I am sure most of which was wrong) to get there.  "Switch checkout", "revert changes by this", "reset BLAH to this".

Then it got messy and somehow I've got to a point where the repo I started with now has a green branch label (I don't know why it's green and I don't want it to be a branch), and my latest entry has a red branch label and a peachy "origin/Branch..." label.

The branches in the original clone aren't represented as offshoots in the log - it's just one line.

The third generation clone now won't update with anything new. Even if I delete it and clone it all over again. Although I do see references to the new stuff in the response back when I pull it doesn't show in the actual repo log.

Do I need to somehow merge my branches in the first clone?
Do I need to reset the head somehow?
Have I broken everything?

Sorry if anything is unclear - I must admit I haven't quite gripped the lingo. I do thank anyone for any nugget of info they can offer. :)

Comment: Sorry but I find it very hard to follow your explanation. Could you break it down to some major and relevant facts. Maybe explain your self with some graphs of how your repository looks and your goal?

Comment: Maybe if you have multiple questions, split them in multiple posts so it is easier to follow, and it could be reusable for other git beginners

Comment: Thank you both for responding.

I will add a snapshot... :)

Comment: http://testing.devg.es/reposnapshot.jpg

Comment: So inside this snapshot you can see the most recent commit is not marked as origin/master. This is also as far as my second clone will update to. What do I need to do to make the most recent commit the one the second clone updates to?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know this tool and his coloring syntax, I can't help you.

Comment: Please run in console `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` and post the results here.

Comment: This command will show a log without commit messages. Only sha1, branch names, dates. 
`git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset  %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to do to make the most recent commit the one the second
>   clone updates to?

There are a couple of ways you can skin this cat. If you do not want to change the repository itself, in your second clone simply switch to the branch that has the latest commit: `git checkout Branch_871364...`. You would have to do this with each new clone, however. What you *probably* want to know is how to change the repository so that origin/master points to the latest commit, so that new clones will always get the latest. To do that, do the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
git merge Branch_871364... #put the full branch name here
git push
```

After you do that, origin/master will point to the latest commit.

Comment: Thanks for this! That's exactly what I needed! You saved a massive headache! I would love to buy you a pint but instead please accept 10 internets!